# Scala type for object or function returning an object

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I'm getting into Scala and I have a question if what I want to do is possible, or if there's a better way.

I want to be able to take as a parameter a Map whose keys are either strings, or 0-args function returning a string. So for example

```
def main(args: List[String]){
    f = F(
      Map(
      "key" -> "value",
      "key2" ->(()=> {"valule2"})
    )
    )

    println(f("key"))

}
    case class F(arg: Map[String, ???]){
        def apply(s: String): String = {arg(s)}
    }
```

This obviously doesn't compile. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you can use [scala.Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Either)

```
scala> val map: Map[String, Either[String, () => String]] = Map.empty
map: Map[String,Either[String,() => String]] = Map()

scala> map + ("key" -> Left("value"))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Either[String,() => String]] = Map(key -> Left(value))

scala> res0("key")
res1: Either[String,() => String] = Left(value)

scala> map + ("key2" -> Right(() => "value2"))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Either[String,() => String]] = Map(key2 -> Right(<function0>))

scala> res2("key2")
res3: Either[String,() => String] = Right(<function0>)
```

#### Update

You can hide implementation from caller using something like this.

```
def toEither[T <: Any : Manifest](x: T): Either[String, () => String] =
  x match {
    case x: String => Left(x)
    case x: Function0[String] if manifest[T] <:< manifest[() => String] => Right(x)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }
```

The actual type of `Function0` is eliminated due type erasure, but it can be verified with `Manifest`

```
scala> map + ("key" -> toEither("value"))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Either[String,() => String]] = Map(key -> Left(value))

scala> map + ("key2" -> toEither(() => "value2"))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Either[String,() => String]] = Map(key2 -> Right(<function0>))

scala> res2("key2").right.get()
res3: String = value2

scala> map + ("key2" -> toEither(() => 5))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

scala> map + ("key2" -> toEither(false))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

#### Update2

As @Submonoid rightly corrected me in the comments below, there is much simpler way of dealing with `Either`.

```
type StringOrFun = Either[String, () => String]
implicit def either(x: String): StringOrFun = Left(x)
implicit def either(x: () => String): StringOrFun = Right(x)

val m: Map[String, StringOrFun] = Map("key" -> "value", "key2" -> (() => "value2"))
```

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know about `Either`. However, my ultimate goal here is to abstract this differentiation away from the caller so they don't have to wrap the values. I'm not sure that's possible though. I think I might be thinking too much in python still.

Comment: @Falmarri, you can definitely achieve your goal, see my updated answer.

Comment: @submonoid's answer looks more concise :)

Comment: @tuxSlayer, that's because he's not answering the whole question. Op will have to deal with type erasure anyway.

Comment: hm.. I thought we shall have a compilation error on `map + ("key2" -> toEither(() => 5))`.. At least while compiling it not in REPL

Comment: @4e6 In what way am I not answering the whole question? It's not necessary to deal with type erasure because there's no need for pattern matching - one always has a Function0[A]. You could argue about the overhead wrapping a String in a function, but it's no worse than wrapping it in Either.

Comment: @4e6 Also, even if you go down the `Either` route, there's no need for Manifests and reflection: it's perfectly valid to define: `def toEither(s : String) : Either[String, () => String] = Left(s)` and `def toEither(s : () => String) : Either[String, () => String] = Right(s)`, since you can happily dispatch differently on the raw types `String` and `Function0`.

Comment: @Submonoid, +1 you are absolutely right. I've thought how to make it typesafe and completely forgot about overloaded methods.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can wrap any string in a function which evaluates to that string:

```
implicit def delayed[A](a : A) = () => a
val m = Map[String, () => String]("a" -> "b", "c" -> (() => "d"))
```